# Is this function differentiable at x=0?

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined as $f(x)=\begin{cases}
> &x\cos\left(\frac1x\right) &&: x\ne0\\
> &0 &&: x = 0
> \end{cases}$

True/False: $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$

So far, using the definition of a derivative, I have obtained:
$$f'(0) = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{0-0}{h} = D.N.E$$

So my initial gut reaction is that this statement is false, but I believed there is more to it.

I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have had
$$f'(0) = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{ h \cos(1/h) - 0}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \cos\left( \frac 1h \right)$$
which clearly does not exist.

Comment: Could you explain why you pulled in the part of the function that's not defined at $x=0$?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what you mean.

Comment: @Cody_15243 The first term in the limit is the behaviour of the function *around* $x=0$ not *at* that point. It would be a mistake to pull in the part of the function defined at $x=0$.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. Thank you for your help!